# Relations between SU(N) and CP$^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, complex-geometry

Is this true that
$$
\frac{SU(N)}{SU(N-1) \times U(1)} = CP^{N-1}
$$
Can we show or explain this more precisely?

The $CP^n$ is the complex projective space here.

Comment: Can you think of an action of SU(n) on $P^{n-1}$?

Comment: Another hint: See Claim 2.0.3 (p.6) in [Classical homogeneous spaces](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj98dbI7s_ZAhWDj5QKHdTsDR0QFghUMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-users.math.umn.edu%2F~garrett%2Fm%2Fmfms%2Fnotes%2F08_homogeneous.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2JwwlqXUzMjEOcxoEK1T8L) by Paul Garrett.

Comment: If $l\in \bf CP ^{N-1}$ is a line, consider the orthogonal symmetry which induces the identity on $l$ and $-Id$ on its orthogonal. Its normalizer in $SU(N)$ is precisely $S (U(1)\times U(N-1)$

Comment: With this explanation you see that $CP^(N-1)$ is not only an homogeneous space, but in fact a symmetric space.

Comment: Is $P^{n−1}$ a real projective space here? Thanks